# Ip Man Wing Chun book didn't cover deep breathing

Tags: tai-chi, wing-chun, breathing

It seems the Ip Man syllabus removed deep breathing for Siu Lim Tao part 1. Anyone has idea why the part is removed?

[image: Front cover of Traditional Wing Chun: The branch of great master Yip Man by Igor Dudukchan] ([Google Books link](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Traditional_Wing_Chun_The_branch_of_grea/1P5CDwAAQBAJ?hl=en))

From [this blog entry](https://www.kungfufxbg.com/blog/speeded-up-slow-siu-nim-tao-ving-tsun-wing-chun-kung-fu):

> This video shows the Ving Tsun (wing chun) Kung Fu form, Siu Nim Tao,
> with a certain part played at a very slow rate of movement. To an
> observer, it appears the practitioner may simply be standing still,
> but the student practicing feels the whole body alive with movement
> and energy.
>
> This exercise develops discipline and mental focus, as well as
> Centerline awareness, relaxed deep breathing, and powerful legs with
> good balance from the horse stance training.

Comment: Are you asking about Igor's book? The video? Statements by Yip Man on his syllabus?

Comment: @MacacoBranco asking about the books and also the Ip Man's classes from his branches student. None of them i "found" teaching deep breathing. This video from Ip Man didn't look like doing deep breathing also - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iecU5Ch3_-E

Comment: @MacacoBranco Siu Lim Tao (Part 1) is form of standing meditation. Deep breathing is the essence for whole body relaxation. See this lady and compare with Ip Man did it. The belly is bloating on and off - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K353fkHYMPs

Comment: William Cheung has a book out on using Sil Lim Tao called "How to Develop Chi Power". It's not about chi-kung as such, but it supposedly goes over breathing and leading chi through the body. Personally, I think if your goal is to understand chi-kung, you learn it from someone who specializes in it. And then you find someone who can show you how that is applied to martial arts. And usually that means doing something like Taiji, particularly Yang style. But Wing Chun is fine, too. The principles stay the same no matter what the martial expression is.

Comment: @SteveWeigand would like to know why Ip Man removes that deep breathing. His son Ip Ching said modified so all people can follow. Not sure is related to spiritual study cause all these from Shaolin. Shaolin founder is Buddhism Zen sifu.

Comment: @littlestar If Ip Ching said that, and you trust that Ip Ching was given the right instruction by his dad, then that's your answer. If Ip Man did say that he got rid of it so that it didn't get in the way of learning wing chun, then he must have thought that it was not important. Probably he saw that breathing comes naturally and doesn't need to be given much attention. At least maybe until much later on in a student's training. Wing Chun does have that philosophy overall, the idea that you teach the most useful stuff first and then add secondary stuff later. My thoughts.

Comment: @SteveWeigand let me ask Dennis Lee if I have chance to see him, Ip Ching's student :) I supposed to attend his class  if covid didn't happen